# Custom Views in ExpandableListView don't get click events

Tags: android, focus, expandablelistview, ime

I have an ExpandableListView in my activity with two groups.  Each group has a custom View.  I can click on buttons in each group and it works.  If I click on a text field in one group's custom view, the soft keyboard is displayed.  But once I dismiss it, no clicks are registered in either group.  The ExpanableListView loses focus after the keyboard is dismissed.  How can I set the focus back on the list view once a dialog is dismissed?  If I collapse and expand the groups, it gets reset. I have tried various listeners to no avail.

My class and layout are a little more complicated, but I stripped it off to the bare minimum and here is my code.

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class TestOnClickActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String cLogTag = "TestOnClick";

    private ExpadableAdapter iExpandableListAdapter;
    private ExpandableListView iExpandableList;
    private View[] iSearchViews;


    private class ExpadableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter 
    {
        private String[] iGroups = 
        {
            "Search By Device",
            "Search By Date",
        };

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int theGroupPosition, int theChildPosition)
        {
            return "NA";
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int theGroupPosition, int theChildPosition)
        {
            return theGroupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int theGroupPosition)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int theGroupPosition, 
                                 int theChildPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, 
                                 View theConvertView, 
                                 ViewGroup theParent)
        {
            return iSearchViews[theGroupPosition];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int theGroupPosition)
        {
            return iGroups[theGroupPosition];
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount()
        {
            return iGroups.length;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int theGroupPosition)
        {
            return theGroupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int theGroupPosition, 
                                 boolean theIsExpanded,
                                 View theConvertView, 
                                 ViewGroup theParent)
        {
            if (theConvertView == null) {
                Context theContext = TestOnClickActivity.this;
                TextView theTV = new TextView(theContext, 
                                              null, 
                                              android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium);
                theTV.setText(iGroups[theGroupPosition]);
                return theTV;

            } else {
                return theConvertView;  
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds()
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int theGroupPosition,
                                         int theChildPosition)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle theSavedState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(theSavedState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        iExpandableListAdapter = new ExpadableAdapter();
        iExpandableList = 
                (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.searchOptionsListView);
        iExpandableList.setAdapter(iExpandableListAdapter);
        iExpandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        createSearchViews();
    }

    private void createSearchViews()
    {
        iSearchViews = new View[2];
        LinearLayout theRowView;

        // Create the Search By Device View
        LayoutInflater theInflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
                                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        theRowView = new LinearLayout(this);
        theInflator.inflate(R.layout.search1, theRowView, true);
        iSearchViews[0] = theRowView;

        // Create the Search By Date View
        theRowView = new LinearLayout(this);
        theInflator.inflate(R.layout.search2, theRowView, true);
        iSearchViews[1] = theRowView;
    }
}
```

The layout files are main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/searchOptionsListView"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"        
        android:childDivider="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

search1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/searchByDeviceIdLinearLayout"
   android:paddingLeft="36dp"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
       android:text="@string/deviceId"/>

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/deviceIdEditText"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:inputType="number" >
   </EditText>

  <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/searchButton"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:contentDescription="@string/search"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_search" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and search2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/searchByDateLinearLayout"
    android:paddingLeft="36dp"      
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/searchButton"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:contentDescription="@string/search"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_search" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the problem of loss of focus is the result of another problem.
Your adapter is not constructed properly. Be aware that for each item displayed on the screen, it will pass in the getChildView and getGroupView methods.
That's why the name of the group changed each time you click on it.

If i add some log in those method i can see :

```
01-24 11:18:02.575: D/TEST(443): > createSearchViews
01-24 11:18:02.715: D/TEST(443): > getGroupView : position=0
01-24 11:18:02.715: D/TEST(443): > getGroupView : position=1
01-24 11:18:02.755: D/TEST(443): > getGroupView : position=0
01-24 11:18:02.755: D/TEST(443): > getGroupView : position=1
01-24 11:18:02.845: D/TEST(443): > getGroupView : position=0
01-24 11:18:02.845: D/TEST(443): > getGroupView : position=1
01-24 11:18:02.885: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.test/.TestOnClickActivity: 455 ms (total 455 ms)
01-24 11:18:02.905: D/TEST(443): > getGroupView : position=0
01-24 11:18:02.905: D/TEST(443): > getGroupView : position=1
01-24 11:18:08.246: D/TEST(443): > getGroupView : position=0
01-24 11:18:08.246: D/TEST(443): > getGroupView : position=1
01-24 11:18:08.246: D/TEST(443): > getChildView : position=1
01-24 11:18:08.256: D/TEST(443): > getGroupView : position=0
01-24 11:18:08.256: D/TEST(443): > getGroupView : position=1
01-24 11:18:08.256: D/TEST(443): > getChildView : position=1
```

In this example I only clicked on one of the group.
you need to completely rethink your adapter for this to work

For exemple in my code i have something like :

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public View getGroupView(int p_iSecteurPosition, boolean p_bIsExpanded, View p_oConvertView, ViewGroup p_oParent) {
    if (p_oConvertView==null){
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        p_oConvertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.maquette_recherche_avancee_secteur_item_layout, null);
    }

    String sLabel = (String) getGroup(p_iSecteurPosition);
    TextView oVoieLabel = (TextView) p_oConvertView.findViewById(R.id.maquette_secteur_label);
    oVoieLabel.setText(sLabel);

    return p_oConvertView;
}


/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public View getChildView(int p_iSecteurPosition, int p_iVoiePosition, boolean p_bIsLastChild, View p_oConvertView, ViewGroup p_oParent) {
    if (p_oConvertView==null){
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        p_oConvertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.maquette_recherche_avancee_voie_item_layout, null);
    }

    String sLabel = (String) getChild(p_iSecteurPosition, p_iVoiePosition);
    TextView oVoieLabel = (TextView) p_oConvertView.findViewById(R.id.maquette_voie_label);
    oVoieLabel.setText(sLabel);

    CheckBox oCheck= (CheckBox) p_oConvertView.findViewById(R.id.maquette_voie_selection);
    oCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    p_oConvertView.setTag(FBO_KEY, p_iSecteurPosition+SEPARATOR+p_iVoiePosition);

    return p_oConvertView;
}
```

a simple tutorial here :
http://androgue.blogspot.com/2011/08/android-expandablelistview-tutorial.html

hope i could help
François

Comment: The name of my group does not change every time I click on it.  The difference between your code and mine seems to be that I create the row views once in onCreate, while your code is setting them up every time getGroupView and getChildView are getting called.  I'll try it out and see if it makes a difference.